# Cannot access property from object returned by Promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

I have the following object:

```
const api = {
    post: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({
                response: {
                    data: {
                        token: "abcdefghijkl",
                    },
                 },
              });
        })
      }
   };
```

When I do `api.post().then((res) => console.log(res.data))`
I get `undefined` even though `console.log(res)` prints the entire object.

Comment: You're passing `resolve` an object with a top-level property of `response`. It has no top-level `data` property

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const api = {
    post: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({
                response: {
                    data: {
                        token: "abcdefghijkl",
                    },
                 },
              });
        })
      }
   };

api.post().then((res) => console.log(res.response.data))
```

Comment: Though it is obvious, can you add explanation about what was wrong and what did you change to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

Should be `res.response.data`

```
api.post().then((res) => console.log(res.response.data)
```

Or if you want to access it by `res.data`, update the object you returned from promise to

```
resolve({
  data: {
    token: "abcdefghijkl",
  }
});
```